# Response times in Apache logs don't appear sometimes

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files

Some records in Apache logs show response time and some don't. Why is that?

Example:

```
10.2.4.6 - - [10/May/2017:16:45:49 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 337 "-" "-"
8.9.21.3 - - [10/May/2017:16:45:48 +0000] "POST /url HTTP/1.1" 200 145618 "-" "-" 1323575µs
```

I have two LogFormats but they are identical.

Apache config:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %Dµs" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %Dµs" proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log proxy env=forwarded
```